# read cookie from server in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, cookies

I am doing login site. Here's my code:

```
$scope.signin = function() {
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'server_url',
    data: $.param({
      action: 'sign_in',
      username: $scope.username,
      password: $scope.password
    }),
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  })
    .then(function(response) {
    $rootScope.valueCookie = $cookies.get('AuthSession');
    console.log($rootScope.valueCookie);
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="username" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="signin()">Sign in</button>
```

In my server response i get cookie "AuthSession", here's image:

[image]
I wan't to ascribe this cookie to $rootScope. Is it possible? My code doesn't work, in console.log i get "undefinded".

Comment: What is the result of `response`?

Comment: In image in console.log

Comment: if your cookie is set to httponly (which is your case), you won't be able to get the value in js. It is sent automatically as http header, but not accessible here

Comment: @RameshRajendran data, status, config, statusText, headers

Comment: @Kaddath So how can i check this cookies?

Comment: @bafix2203 if you use cookies for Authentification on a server, it is better that they stay httponly, it is not the client's role to check the cookie, but the server's one, and he will get it as a header automatically. If you want an info to display, the server should send you separately (a cookie not httponly, json, anything)